# GCD Cancel and restart queue when button pressed again

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

Simply, I have a button that adds to a queue, or I believe that's how it works - I've only just started to use GCD. If I press the button twice in my app, it runs these two processes in parallel and the progress bar races back and forth between them, I'd like to stop all the other instances of the queue and execute a new one if that makes sense, I've not got to grips with the lingo...

```
@IBAction func makePi(_ sender: UIButton) {
    piProgress.progress = 0.0
    let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.queue1", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)
    queue1.async {
        let currentAmount = Int(self.randNum.value)
        var gcdCounter = 0

        for n in 1...currentAmount {
            if self.gcd(self.random(max: Int(self.randRange.value)), self.random(max: Int(self.randRange.value))) == 1{
                gcdCounter += 1
            }
            if n % 1000 == 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.piProgress.setProgress(Float(Double(n)/Double(currentAmount)), animated: true)
                }
            } else if n == currentAmount {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.piProgress.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }

        let piFinal = sqrt(Double((6/Double((Double(gcdCounter)/Double(currentAmount))))))
        let roundedAccuracy: Double = ((piFinal-Double.pi)/Double.pi*100).roundTo(places: 6)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.piLabel.text = String(piFinal)
            self.piAccuracy.text = "Accuracy: \(roundedAccuracy)%"
        }
    }
}
```

I just need all the other queue1.async ones to stop...

P.s. If I've done anything *obviously* wrong, please help ^^ Thanks.

Comment: Use `NSOperationQueue` instead

Comment: NSOperationQueue is probably a nicer API and the way to go here, as @Andy said, but if you want to stick with GCD, check out DispatchWorkItem which is new as of swift 3 (I think?). You can cancel those guys.

Comment: @Andy  Is there any good reference, through searching I could only find tutorials on GCD or the differences between GCD and NSOperationQueue, but no content I can find itself... Thanks.

Comment: @Skidushe sorry I don't have anything to suggest. The best would be to check objc.io or nshipster.com for articles